# Android Studio 6.0.1 Marshmallow - Sending MMS

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, mms

Is there any way to send MMS in android 6.0.1 Marshmallow and higher?

Recently I've been working on a project to send and receive SMS and MMS. So far I can send and receive SMS and I can receive MMS, but I cannot send MMS.

I know this question has been asked before but those questions are no longer valid.

These requires APNs (specifically MMSC-URL) which are no longer accessible above android 4.0 (or somewhere near that):

[how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android)

[send-mms-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518393/send-mms-programmatically)

[unable-to-send-mms-using-smsmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862925/unable-to-send-mms-using-smsmanager)

And these just use an Intent which is not really an option:

[android-sending-audio-file-with-mms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213017/android-sending-audio-file-with-mms)

[to-send-mms-with-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221810/to-send-mms-with-image)

There are many more I've seen that are basically the same.
There was also one (can't seem to find it now) that didn't use APNs or Intents but I had to include like 20 or 30 classes, but they were incomplete and didn't work, even if it did work though I would prefer not to multiply my app size by 10.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issues as you do

Comment: @FMontano No, I'm just using an intent for now. I can't find anything about MMS for modern versions, google has basically just locked everyone out that can't host their own server to handle it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is the method SmsManager.sendMultimediaMessage() which works for api_21 and above.

It doesn't require the APNs, as far as I know that is the only way to send Mms in 6.01. I have not tested is but you might be able to send it via HttpConnection but then you would have to prompt the user to enter the APNs which I know is not very desirable.